# Django Rest Framework - is it possible to add sorting to pagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following code

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

class ListAllPrePayedV2(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PrePayedSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = PrePayed.objects

        # lcode
        lcode = self.request.query_params.get('lcode', None)
        if lcode is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(lcode=lcode)

        # lcode
        payed_by = self.request.query_params.get('payed_by', None)
        if payed_by is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(payed_by__icontains=payed_by)

        # order_by_date
        order_by_date = self.request.query_params.get('order_by_date', None)
        if order_by_date is not None:
            queryset = queryset.order_by('date')

        # order_by_payed_at
        order_by_payed_at = self.request.query_params.get('order_by_payed_at', None)
        if order_by_payed_at is not None:
            queryset = queryset.order_by('payed_at')

        if order_by_payed_at is None and order_by_date is None:
            queryset = queryset.order_by('pk')

        return queryset
```

the problem is that sorting never works. is it possible in such set-up or I do something wrong ? if not possible in this, how can I do it ?

Comment: Can you please let us know the url along with the params you are using listing for the ordering is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this that's works for me

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

class ListAllPrePayedV2(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = PrePayed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PrePayedSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):

        # lcode
        lcode = self.request.query_params.get('lcode', None)
        if lcode is not None:
            queryset = PrePayed.objects.filter(lcode=lcode)

        # lcode
        payed_by = self.request.query_params.get('payed_by', None)
        if payed_by is not None:
            queryset = PrePayed.objects.filter(payed_by__icontains=payed_by)

        # order_by_date
        order_by_date = self.request.query_params.get('order_by_date', None)
        if order_by_date is not None:
            queryset = PrePayed.objects.order_by('date')

        # order_by_payed_at
        order_by_payed_at = self.request.query_params.get('order_by_payed_at', None)
        if order_by_payed_at is not None:
            queryset = PrePayed.objects.order_by('payed_at')

        if order_by_payed_at is None and order_by_date is None:
            queryset = PrePayed.objects.order_by('pk')

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, pagination and ordering can be considered as completely separate from each other. As far as ordering goes, any reason to not use the [ordering provided by django-filter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter)?